# Are there known issues with New Relic Script and Google Tag Manager

Tags: newrelic, google-tag-manager

So I notice that on some pages google tag manager fires when I click on elements but some pages it doesnt. The issue is coming from a line of code like this...

```
return n=t.apply(d,a)
```

it return null and kills further execution of the code. Making is impossible to reach Google Tag Manager Script.

Is anyone else having issues with google tag manager and New Relic ?? let me know.. Thanks

Comment: A way to reproduce the errors you're seeing would be very helpful in troubleshooting this.

Comment: yes, when you have another js taking over clicks, tagManager doesn't have a chance to catch an event. Haven't seen it with NR but i saw this problem with some ajax forms etc. I think the best would be to contact NR support since they're paid to find a solution ;)